# Convert Word of interop object to byte [] without saving physically

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word, byte

I have an object created in memory using **Microsoft.Office.Interop** and  **Microsoft.Office.Word** and with all created, paragraphs, tables and the like. I need this object to generate a content byte [] to feed one field of the same type in a table.
The problem that I can not save it in any way physically with a oDoc.Save ("path") in order to use a FileStream and solve my problem.

Have tried several solutions and how to use the clipboard, and did not work. Any solution?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you show some code?

Comment: I wonder if saving to a named pipe might work... But - writing to the TEMP are is a lot easier...

Comment: Marc, i dont writing in TEMP because dont have any permission to write in FS.

Comment: keyboardP, the code :
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Word.Application oWord;
Word.Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
Word.Paragraph oPara1;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
oPara1.Range.Text = "The title;
oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
byte[] content = new byte[oDoc.Content.Text.Length];
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
content = encoding.GetBytes(oDoc.Content.Text);

This return the text w/o formt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really have to use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` and `Microsoft.Office.Word`?

If it is not really necessary, you could use the [OpenXML SDK libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124)  for manipulating the content of the WordDocument.

OpenXML SDK contains a class `WordprocessingDocument` that can manipulate a memory stream containing a WordDocument content. And `MemoryStream` can be converted using `ToArray()` to a `byte[]`.

As a code sample:

```
byte[] templateContent = File.ReadAllBytes(templateFile);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(templateContent, 0, templateContent.Length);

WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);

// When done
byte[] contentOfWordFile = stream.toArray();
```

Comment: You actually don't even need the `File.ReadAllBytes()`, etc. part, because `WordprocessingDocument` will accept the file path, directly, instead of requiring the stream to be created outside, like that.  You would do `using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true)) { using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream())) { string docText = sr.ReadToEnd(); } XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); xml.LoadXml(docText);  // do stuff with XmlNodes…` And then you would have `docText = xml.OuterXml;` that could then be converted to bytes.

Comment: The only problem with my method is you are then encoding a string of XML into bytes for the database:  `byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(docText);` , so you have to remember that if you want to reconstitute the file back to a docx you'd need to convert the bytes back to a string, then need `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {                    
                    sw.Write(docText);
                }`

Comment: Talks all about it:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part

Comment: Well, I also found that encoding the bytes is bad and doesn't work... it corrupts the file if you write it back out.  I had to use `File.ReadAllBytes()` to read it, then `File.WriteAllBytes()` for it to be accurate.  You can write the string of XML like I described, but converting bytes back to string doesn't work, because the encoding (whether you use UTF8, Unicode, Default, UTF7, ASCII, doesn't matter) will corrupt it.

Comment: Converting it to `byte[]` from a stream with `.ToArray()` also works, and using `using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);

                // Save the file with the new name
                File.WriteAllBytes(strDocumentPath, stream.ToArray());
            }` to write it back out also is a way to convert it back and forth successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is a dynamically-created Word document.

Since you have the document in the form of a `Document` object, you should be able to get its string of XML, then bytes, by doing this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document d = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

// All of your building of the document was here
// The object must be updated with content

string docText = d.WordOpenXML;  // this assumes content is here
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(docText);
```

I don't think that saving the object to the file system first is required, since you already have the object you have built all dynamically, in memory.  It should just be a matter of accessing its `WordOpenXML`.

If you were grabbing the file from the file system, it would look pretty much the same, except for how the document is opened first:

```
string sourceFilePath = @"C:\test.docx";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var document = wordApp.Documents.Open(sourceFilePath);
string docText = document.WordOpenXML;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(docText);
```

If you ever want to download these bytes back into a document, you'd need to do this:

```
string documentPath = @"C:\test.docx"; // can be modified with dynamic paths, file name from database, etc.
byte[] contentBytes = null;
// … Fill contentBytes from the database, then...

// Create the Word document using the path
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(documentPath, true))
{
    // This should get you the XML string...
    string docText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contentBytes);

    // Then we write it out...
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {                    
        sw.Write(docText);
    } 
}
```

See [How can I form a Word document using stream of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056852/how-can-i-form-a-word-document-using-stream-of-bytes/53382112#53382112) for more information.