# Converting WordDoc in memory

Tags: c#, office-interop

Given the following code fragment

```
wordApp.Documents.Open(FileName: wordDoc, Visible: false); 

if (wordApp.Documents.Count > 0)
{
      _Document thisDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
      thisDoc.SaveAs(FileName: rtfDoc, FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);
```

Can anyone suggest a method to perform this conversion **without saving to disk?**

I want the raw text of the rtf document in memory, perhaps as a StringBuilder object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is just **not possible**.

With Office Interop, there is **NO** way to use such methods (`Open`, `SaveAs`) with something else than a valid file (so it must exist or be saved on the disk or somewhere else).

What you need to keep in mind, is that Interop allows you to do at most what you could do with the Office application itself. And there is currently no way to work with `MemoryStream` with Office Application, just existing files.

Working with `MemoryStream` is possible with OpenXML SDK. Unfortunately, OpenXml SDK does not provide method to convert to Rtf format.

See also: [How can I form a Word document using stream of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056852/how-can-i-form-a-word-document-using-stream-of-bytes)

Comment: Thanks @Chris - I figured that was the likely answer but wanted confirmation.

Comment: @HughJones You are welcome :) Although the answer is no, the question makes sense.